# Why are there 2 entries of bcrypt in my anaconda distribution?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to install python bcrypt in pip in a shared host account. I have anaconda 4 installed as my default python distro. I notice that when I run
'conda list', I get:

```
astropy                   1.1.2               np110py27_0
babel                     2.2.0                    py27_0
backports_abc             0.4                      py27_0
bcrypt                    3.1.1                     <pip>
bcrypt                    3.1.1                    py27_0
beautifulsoup4            4.4.1                    py27_0
binaryornot               0.4.0                     <pip>
bitarray                  0.8.1                    py27_0
blaze                     0.9.1                    py27_0
```

Why are there 2 entries of bcrypt in my anaconda distribution? Also just noticed 2 versions of cffi:

```
cdecimal                  2.3                      py27_0
cffi                      1.9.1                     <pip>
cffi                      1.5.2                    py27_0
chardet                   2.3.0                     <pip>
```

Is this a problem?

Comment: apparently one is coming with Python and another one was installed with pip

Comment: I've been trying to install bcrypt to run a flask app (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725994/python-flask-bcrypt-invalid-elf-header) and have been getting some weird errors. I'm wondering if I should uninstall either the anaconda version or pip version to try to fix this. Any advice?